# What does it mean that inserts carry "discoursal meanings"?

Tags: linguistics, discourse-markers

According to Biber's *Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English*, insterts are one of the three families of words (apart from lexical and functional words).

At some point, the author explains that inserts

> generally carry emotional and discoursal meanings, such as oh, ah,
>   wow, used to express a speaker's emotional response to a situation, or
>   yeah, no, okay used to signal a response to what has just been said.

Could someone,please, explain in simple words, what does the 'discoursal meaning' mean?

Comment: He says what it means in the text. Discoursal meanings 'express a speaker's emotional response to a situation,' or they are 'used to signal a response to what has just been said'. They're also called 'exclamations', 'interjections', [or 'discourse markers'](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=discourse+markers).

Comment: Another (perhaps hypernymic) term is 'pragmatic marker'. There are many different types, but they all 'frame' the matrix sentence (ie don't affect the primary statement, but do help by structuring / explaining /  giving an opinion on how true it is / giving some other comment from the writer / adding politeness or a friendly feel ... (ie making the flow of discourse smoother in some way). Many examples are given here: search for "pragmatic marker". Bruce Fraser's 'Pragmatic Markers' (1996) (Google "Simply stated, I take pragmatics") is a classic article.